# Data transer from a local database to a remote database using windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a challenge I’ve been battling with for over a week now which is getting me frustrated.

I’m developing a project that has two parts; a web (ASP.NET) and a windows client (Winforms C#). Data is to be captured on the windows application and a windows service is supposed to schedule a transfer of records from the database on the local machine to a remote database. Creating the windows service is not a problem at all as I have created others in past projects to handle Email services and Short Message Service (SMS). But the code to handle the data transfer is the real problem here.

I’ve searched the internet for help but couldn’t find any that matches my requirement. Any help suggested here will be deeply appreciated.

Many Thanks y’all.

Answer (score 0):

Data transfer is not problem if you have access (connection strings) to databases. Just use ADO.NET. [Using ADO.NET for beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8477/Using-ADO-NET-for-beginners)

Comment: Thank you for your response Truba. But I'm not using ADO.NET in the project. I'm actually using Nettiers to generate my business logic and data classes. Plus I will need a technique that won't give any issues when the application is on production level. Thank you